# Bootstrap header grid layout & CSS transition with jquery not working well on iPad & iPhones

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm relatively new to web dev world and have adopted bootstrap & jquery to build a responsive website. My website runs well on all devices except iOS ones.The header, which contains the logo and the navigation menu, is where the problem is arising. Transition animations are extremely slow, almost to a point of not working(both on safari & chrome for iOS). And the bootstrap grid layout isn't working too well either. My logo column is too big and is not resizing based on grid size. Here's the code for the header :

**HTML :**

```
<header id="mainHead">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-left">
                    <img class="mainLogo" src="img/logos/logo.png" alt="logo" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                    <ul class="listOptions navigationList text-right">
                        <li class="listEntryOptions">ABOUT</li>
                        <li class="listEntryOptions"><a href="#menu">MENU</a></li>
                        <li class="listEntryOptions"><a href="#reservations">RESERVATIONS</a></li>
                        <li class="listEntryOptions"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </header>
```

**jQuery (for header resize animation effect):**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
        $('.mainLogo').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('.mainLogo').removeClass("sticky");
    }


   });
```

**CSS:**

```
#mainHead {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF; 
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.mainLogo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 20%;
  width: auto;
      transition: all 1s ease;
}

.sticky {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10%;
  width: auto;
  transition: all 1s ease;

}
```

What would be the best way to fix these issues for iOS devices? Is there something I'm not doing correctly? Would love any feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination would be to adjust the scroll function--it fires repeatedly--like every time the window moves, and adds the `sticky` class over and over again.

See this demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8tekyau/)

Open the console to see the logs demonstrating how that function is being fired repeatedly. Aside from that, I couldn't really tell what was supposed to animate from the fiddle...

(edited to add--I added that hideous css3 fill just to give a visual indicator that the area was scrolling).

Comment: The sticky class resizes the logo image based on the position of the page. The effect is, when I'm at top of the page, the logo image , and in turn the header, is wider. When I scroll down, the logo image reduces in size, and hence the header width becomes thinner. here's an example of a website with similar behavior, 

[link]http://engageinteractive.co.uk/culture 

however you're right, I should probably handle this in a better way rather than constantly firing the scroll function